# SQL Server CTE hierarchy?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table which has hierarchy in it.

Lets start with `Id = 5`; this is the child. (a **given** start parameter  - from user)

Algorithm:

- give me the `first` value which you have encountered for `id = 5`
- if you haven't found value for `id = 5`, go to its parent and give me his `id`
- if this parent also doesn't have a value - go to its parent ... etc (until parent has no parent - `parentId = 0`)

p.s. the result here should be 7.

if 7 value was empty so  : 9

end if 9 was also empty so : 1

I'm trying to do this with CTE but no success..

p.s. I **want** a solution with CTE. :)

[image]

What I have tried  (don't even look at it - it doesn't work):

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT  
       id,VALUE,parentid

  FROM [test].[dbo].[tmp]   WHERE id=5
  UNION ALL

  SELECT  
      id,VALUE,parentid
  FROM  [tmp]   WHERE parentId=cte.parentId ) //ERROR : The multi-part identifier "cte.parentId" could not be bound.
  SELECT * FROM cte
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join in your cte:

```
with cte as (
select
    id,
    value,
    parentid
from
    [tmp]
where 
    id=5
union all
select
    tmp.id,
    coalesce(cte.value, tmp.value) as value,
    tmp.parentid
from  
    [tmp]
    inner join cte on
        tmp.id = cte.parentId
)
select
    max(value) as value
from
    cte
```

If you're going to reference a table, you need to make sure that you've joined it somewhere in your `from` clause. In this case, you hadn't, which is why it was throwing the error.

Comment: your query returns all rows. it suppose to return only 7.

Comment: Added the `coalesce` statement. Now, if you want to start at some arbitrary point and find the value, then you can just select the top 1 of that and grab the value, since it will bubble the `cte.value` all the way up through.

Comment: thanks fot your effort but : If i put the valud of id=5  NULL so it returns me Null,9,9 What am i suppose to do with 3 items ? how can i take the needed value ?

Comment: Changed it to `max(value)`. That way, it just grabs the first non-null value.