# The best solution for dynamich find relation tree in tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to extract a heiraki of relation from my customer relation table. Im not sure that i can use CTE on this one so i have decited to ask for advise on this.

I have table looking like this

```
table Customerrelations
customer1Id, customer2Id  
1               3
2               5   
3               4
4               5
4               6
4               7
5               19
```

It show a simple relation between two customerIds,

lets take a look on this:

customer 1 relates to 3 and 
3 relates to 4 
4 relates to 5 ,6 and 7

so here i have tree levels

```
1-3 -> 
       3-4 ->
              4-5
              4-6
              6-7
```

But what is the best way to write sql to extract lets say up to max 5 levels of relations on a heiraky like this.

I hope this makes sense

Comment: Recursive CTE or 5 Self Join

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749502/sql-server-cte-hierarchy

Comment: Thank you, i am not sure that i have understod the CTE right when i try following using this code `with cte as (
    select Customer1Id
    , Customer2Id
    , 1 as lvl
    from CustomerRelations
    where Customer1Id = 1 
    union all
    select cr.Customer1Id, cr.Customer2Id, 2 as lvl 
    from  CustomerRelations cr 
    inner join cte on cte.Customer1Id = cr.Customer2Id
    union all
    select cr2.Customer1Id, cr2.Customer2Id, 3 as lvl 
    from  CustomerRelations cr2 
    inner join cte on cte.Customer1Id = cr2.Customer2Id
) 
select * from cte` It doesnt give me other than 1 - 3 -1